# Looping over columns and changing Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called myTable where some values are null.

[image]

I want to replace all null values in all columns with the previous non null value. I found some code that iterates over each row for a specific column, and changes Null Values as I want.

```
DECLARE @value AS int
UPDATE myTable 
SET
   @value = COALESCE(col2, @value),
   col2 = COALESCE(col2, @value)
```

Result:

[image]

This does what I want it do do but only for one column at the time. My goal is to alter the code above in some way so that I can automatically loop over each column in the table.

I ran into several issues when trying to achieve this. Here is my attempt

```
DECLARE @ColNames table (NAMES nvarchar(50), ARRAYINDEX int identity(1,1) )  
INSERT INTO @ColNames (NAMES)  
VALUES ('col1'),('col2'),('col3')

DECLARE @INDEXVAR int  
DECLARE @TOTALCOUNT int  
SET @INDEXVAR = 0  
SELECT @TOTALCOUNT = COUNT(*) FROM @ColNames

WHILE @INDEXVAR < @TOTALCOUNT 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @curColName nvarchar (50)  
    SELECT @INDEXVAR = @INDEXVAR + 1  
    SELECT @curColName = NAMES from @ColNames where ARRAYINDEX = @INDEXVAR  
    DECLARE @value AS int
    UPDATE myTable 
    SET
        @value = COALESCE(@curColName, @value),
        @curColName = COALESCE(@curColName, @value)
END
```

The issues that I have found and not been able to solve are the following:

1. @curColName is just a nvarchar variable and not a representation of my actual column, even if the names are the same. This gives me errors on both lines inside the SET statement.
2. When hard coding the column names in my loop inside the BEGIN/END statement., the script fills out ALL Null values with a number. So col2 gets the value 3 on ALL rows, not only row 2 and 3 as my previous example.

If these two points are hard or impossible to solve, is there an easier way of solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You state in your question you want to replace the `NULL` *"with the next non null value"*, however, in your expected results you have `col2` containing the previous non-`NULL` value and `col1` is completely unaffected. So is it just `col2` you want to target, and you actually want to assign the "previous" (based on the PK) non-`NULL` value?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I meant to say all the previous non-Null values. It has been corrected in the text.
My first code is only meant to go over one column. It was just one step in the right direction but not what I am expecting from the finished solution.

Comment: @lptr Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep this as an alternative if I cant figure out how to loop over each column properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your expected results, and that you actually want to assign the value of `Col2` to be the value of the **previous** non-`NULL` value, when ordered by the column `pk`.

If so, to achieve this you can use an updatable CTE. The first CTE puts the data into groups, based on the non-`NULL` values, and then the second gets the `MAX` value of `Col2` in the group (which would be the non-`NULL` value). Finally you `UPDATE` against that CTE on rows where `Col2` has the value `NULL`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (PK int,
                            Col1 int,
                            Col2 int);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (PK,Col1,Col2)
VALUES(1,2,NULL),
      (2,NULL,3),
      (3,NULL,NULL);
GO

WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT Col2,
           COUNT(Col2) OVER (ORDER BY PK) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
Maxes AS(
    SELECT Col2,
           MAX(Col2) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp) AS MaxCol2
    FROM Groups)
UPDATE Maxes
SET Col2 = MaxCol2
WHERE Col2 IS NULL;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you. How do you suggest I use this approach if I want to do the same things for all columns in an automatic way?
I'm sorry that wasn't clear in my question from the start. I have now edited it.

Comment: You'd need to repeat the same idea for each column, making a group and then max, @JabbaThePadd .